# Measuring string width in Python

Tags: python, string, width

I have some font (Times New Roman, 14) and I need to measure string width. I found matplotlib and example from API:

```
from matplotlib import rcParams
import os.path
afm_filename = os.path.join(rcParams['datapath'], 'fonts', 'afm', 
               'ptmr8a.afm')
from matplotlib.afm import AFM
afm = AFM(open(afm_filename))
afm.string_width_height('What the heck?')
```

But I can't understand what I should paste instead of "datapaths", "fonts", "afm". 
Is it the way to get sting width in Python? Maybe another way?

Comment: string width? do you mean the length of a string?

Comment: The question is, where is your file located?

Comment: Do you mean get string length in pixels?

Comment: My problem is to orginize some text in Word. So, I use python-docx for reading docx document. And I need to measure string width in cm in the document. If I use default settings (in code above):

Comment: Error: if not line.startswith(b'StartFontMetrics'):
TypeError: startswith first arg must be str or a tuple of str, not bytes

Answer (score 3):

```
import tkinter as Tkinter 
from tkinter import font as tkFont

Tkinter.Frame().destroy()
txt = tkFont.Font(family="Times New Roman", size=14)
width = txt.measure("What the heck?")
print(width)
```

Comment: Some error: File "E:/=ПРОЕКТЫ=/=PYTHON=/=ТЕКСТ=/Calc_String_Variants/Calc.py", line 4, in <module>
    txt = tkFont.Font(family="Times New Roman", size=14)
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\tkinter\font.py", line 93, in __init__
    tk.call("font", "create", self.name, *font)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'call'

Comment: it is some add:

Comment: Updated once more. Should work for python 2 and 3.
What do you mean "it is some add" ?

Comment: I add string "tkinter.Frame().destroy()" in Python 3 version and it is work, but it has problem: Width of my Word document is 505 mm. So if I add all letters "a" (230 letters) for full string - the answer is 1840, but if I add all letters "c" (230 letters) for full string - the answer is 2070. It is great difference, but in Word is about the same.

Comment: Updated with destroy()

Comment: Why are you creating and then immediately destroying a Frame? Why not just explicitly create the root window?

Comment: The reason is to not create any widget/window but show string len in pixels. What did you mean under "root window"?

Comment: This is the first answer out of many that correctly measured the width in px.